# React setting initial state based on one of child components parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an app with menu bar and sliding selected menu item indicator. It kind of works, but I have several problems:

1. The initial state (`widthOffset`, `leftOffset` and `color`) is hardcoded, but I need it to always follow the active `NavLink`, so when I open my app - the indicator is immediately in the right place at selected `NavLink` (if you select anything but `Home` `NavLink` and reload app, you will be at last page, but indicator resets to hardcoded state).
2. I did not find a way to get value of `activeStyle` from `e.target`, so colors are also weirdly hardcoded with this double `menuItems.*NavLink name*.color` in each `NavLink`.

What is the best way to implement this?

**full codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-moon-mqbnk

**code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
  const menuItems = {
    Home: {
      color: 'orange',
    },
    About: {
      color: 'green',
    },
    Contacts: {
      color: 'rebeccapurple',
    },
  }

  const [offsetWidth, setWidth] = useState(84);
  const [offsetLeft, setLeft] = useState(26);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("orange");

  function switchMenu(e, color) {
    setWidth(e.target.offsetWidth);
    setLeft(e.target.offsetLeft);
    setColor(color);
  }

  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <NavLink
        refs="Home"
        exact
        className="nav-item"
        activeClassName="nav-item is active"
        activeStyle={{ color: menuItems.Home.color }}
        to="/"
        onClick={(e) => switchMenu(e, menuItems.Home.color)}
      >
        Home
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        refs="About"
        exact
        className="nav-item"
        activeClassName="nav-item is active"
        activeStyle={{ color: menuItems.About.color }}
        to="/about"
        onClick={(e) => switchMenu(e, menuItems.About.color)}
      >
        About
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        refs="Contacts"
        exact
        className="nav-item"
        activeClassName="nav-item is active"
        activeStyle={{ color: menuItems.Contacts.color }}
        to="/contact"
        onClick={(e) => switchMenu(e, menuItems.Contacts.color)}
      >
        Contacts
      </NavLink>
      <span
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: `${offsetLeft}px`,
          width: `${offsetWidth}px`,
          backgroundColor: `${color}`,
          bottom: "0px",
          height: "5px",
          transition: ".4s",
          zIndex: "1",
          borderRadius: "8px 8px 0 0",
        }}
      ></span>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

**UPD:**

I managed o solve some problems, using `isActive` of `NavLink`, now the indicator is always in place, but still have a lil bit of trouble:

1. I am using `onClick` and this destroys the state and rerendering power of React. I did not find a way to toggle `useEffect` to rerender the indicator when I change selected link. Also when I try not to directly change the state `onClick`, but to run `setCurrentPage()` it works 1/2 times, cause `onClick` happens fatser, than className change.
2. If you press `Ctrl + F5` and the fonts, etc. jump - the indicator renders a little bit not in it's place. Would be nice if I could render it after all is settled.

**updated codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-shadow-5jo68

**updated Navigattion.js code:**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
  const [offsetWidth, setWidth] = useState(null);
  const [offsetLeft, setLeft] = useState(null);
  const [color, setColor] = useState(null);

  const Home = useRef(null);
  const About = useRef(null);
  const Contacts = useRef(null);

  const menuItems = {
    Home: {
      ref: Home,
      color: "orange",
    },
    About: {
      ref: About,
      color: "green",
    },
    Contacts: {
      ref: Contacts,
      color: "rebeccapurple",
    },
  };

  function changeIndicator(e, color) {
    setWidth(e.offsetWidth);
    setLeft(e.offsetLeft);
    setColor(color);
  }

  function setCurrentPage() {
    Object.keys(menuItems).forEach((key) => {
      if (
        menuItems[key].ref.current.className === "nav-item nav-item is active"
      ) {
        changeIndicator(menuItems[key].ref.current, menuItems[key].color);
      }
    });
  }

  useEffect(setCurrentPage);

  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <NavLink
        ref={Home}
        isActive={(match) => {
          if (!match) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }}
        exact
        className="nav-item"
        activeClassName="nav-item is active"
        activeStyle={{ color: menuItems.Home.color }}
        to="/"
        onClick={(e) => changeIndicator(e.target, menuItems.Home.color)}
      >
        Home
      </NavLink>
      ...
```

Comment: Why don't you do that using css instead? is it because of the animation?

Comment: @ludwiguer yeah, maybe the animation can be done in css, but that also would be some wierd hardcoded values. I think it is just the exact example where React state would be in it's place.

Comment: I think you can use references to get the offset of the active link at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment you can use references to check what is the active link and then set the state

1. Change your class name to `is-active`

```
  className="nav-item"
  activeClassName="is-active"
```

2. Add references to the links and get the active one (this code can be better)

```
  const homeLink = useRef(null);
  const aboutLink = useRef(null);
  const contactLink = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (homeLink.current.className.includes("is-active")) {
      setWidth(homeLink.current.offsetWidth);
      setLeft(homeLink.current.offsetLeft);
      setColor(menuItems.Home.color);
    } else if (aboutLink.current.className.includes("is-active")) {
      setWidth(aboutLink.current.offsetWidth);
      setLeft(aboutLink.current.offsetLeft);
      setColor(menuItems.About.color);
    } else if (contactLink.current.className.includes("is-active")) {
      setWidth(contactLink.current.offsetWidth);
      setLeft(contactLink.current.offsetLeft);
      setColor(menuItems.Contacts.color);
    }
  }, []);


  ....

  <NavLink
     ref={homeLink}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I made something similar to this and it works better, but still have problems. I updated the question, if you'll have time - it would be nice if you could look at it.